# How to set value of current Numbers cell using Py-Appscript

Tags: python, iwork, sourceforge-appscript

This seems like a straightforward operation but I am stumped.

How do you set value of current Numbers cell using Py-Appscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty tediously, but working:

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> app('Numbers').documents.first.sheets.first.tables.first.selection_range.cells.first.value.set(to=42)
```

That's assuming a simple document.  More generally, you can select items by name:

```
>>> app('Numbers').documents['MyDocument.numbers'].sheets['MySheet'].tables['MyTable'].selection_range.cells.first.value.set(to='abc')
```